# Magento 2 - Compilation from source, errors during `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Tags: magento2, less, static-content-deploy, styles, less-compilation

I get this error when I execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`:

```
Compilation from source: /app/design/frontend/company/fresh/web/css/source/lib/extend/amasty/mega-menu/header.less
variable @md is undefined in file /var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/company/fresh/en_US/css/source/lib/extend/amasty/mega-menu/header.less in header.less on line 22, column 20
20| }
21|
22| @media (min-width: @md) {
23|     .ammenu-menu-toggle {
24|         &:not(.-hamburger) {
25|             margin: 0 .9rem;
```

It says `variable @md is undefined`, even though it is defined:

**MY_THEME\web\css\source\_extend.less**

```
@import 'lib/variables/responsive';  // <--- it is defined here

// Amasty
@import 'lib/extend/amasty/mega-menu/header';
```

## Evidence:

**MY_THEME\web\css\source\lib\variables\responsive.less**

```
@xs: 0;
@xs_sm: 341px;
@xs_md: 381px;
@xs_lg: 471px;
@sm: 576px;
@md: 768px;
@lg: 992px;
@xl: 1200px;
@xxl: 1500px;
```

**MY_THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\amasty\mega-menu\header.less**

```
@media (min-width: @md) {
    .ammenu-menu-toggle {
        &:not(.-hamburger) {
            margin: 0 .9rem;
        }

        .ammenu-icon:before, .ammenu-icon:after {
            background: #6d6d6d;
            width: 25px;
        }
    }
}
```

So why is the error showing?

The compilation is still successfull, but why are the errors showing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Does not make a difference.